# Lost behind the logic of making a stats graphics from a mysql log

Tags: php, mysql, logic, flot

Thanks for reading.
This is not a coding question as much as it is a logic one. But if my current logic is wrong, some coding help would be appreciated.

I have made a table on my database which is a log of everything that happens on my site.
When a user registers, it's saved. When he logs, again. And so on. Each action is represented by a number.

The data looks like this

```
----------------------------
| id | action | timestamp  | 
----------------------------
| 1  | 1      | 1299132900 |
| 2  | 2      | 1346876672 |
| 3  | 14     | 1351983948 |
| 4  | 1      | 1359063373 |
----------------------------
```

ID and action are of type INT(11) and timestamp is TIMESTAMP

I'm using a query to retrieve all records from the last 30 days.

```
SELECT id, action, timestamp FROM log WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

It works, and gives me all the correct values.

I need to arrange this data to make a graphic in flot.

As I see it, there are 2 steps:

1. Group the results by action number.
2. Then, inside each group, separate values by date, so the X axis of the graphic is date and Y axis is count.
3. With those arrays I could make different javascript data arrys to pass to flot.

Am I on the right track?
Should there be several mysql queries, or a GROUP BY clause?
I'm kind of lost here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: `SELECT action, count(action) from ... where ... group by day(from_unixtime(timestamp))` would give you a per-day count of each action.

Comment: Thanks. I tried

    `SELECT action, COUNT(action) FROM log WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) GROUP BY day(from_unixtime(timestamp))`



But it only returns 1 row (with the action number of the last added action) and a count() that sums the total of found results for every action. Am I doing something wrong in the GROUP BY part?

Comment: whoops, right. sorry. `group by day(...), action` will group on action as well.

Comment: That was amazing!!! I really need to learn mysql. It seems like a well constructed query saves hundreds of php lines!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: sql does make things a lot easier in some cases. but it's also a serious pain in the rumb in other things.

Comment: oh, sorry to bother you again. It seems like I got too excited before time. I'm using 
`SELECT timestamp, action, COUNT(action) as total FROM log WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), action` but since it's grouping by day, I only get one day per action (and not all different 30 days with the count of each individual action. It's still using the date an action is first found to group the actions on. :(

Comment: databases can't produce data from nothing. if there were no entries for (say) action 7 on day 3, you don't get a 7/3 record. here's one of those cases where DBs are somewhat of a pain.

Comment: But, for example, I have action 5 recorded on 5 different days (19 to 24 of january). However, for action 5 I only get 1 result. for day 23, which has the lowest ID of all.